# Adding an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, transition

I found a nice jquery slideshow that I want to implement for a friend/client.  Normally I can figure these things out, but for some reason I'm stumped.

I want to use a specific transition, and the documentation provided tells me it's an array that I have to add, otherwise the script uses all the transitions randomly.

This is the basic code:

```
$(function(){
  if(!flux.browser.supportsTransitions)
    alert("Flux Slider requires a browser that supports CSS3 transitions");

  window.f = new flux.slider('#slider', { 
    pagination : true,
  });
});
```

I've got it all working, just not the specific transition.  I've searched and can't find anything that looks like my issue.

i know i use 'transitions' and the transition i want is '[`bars3d`](http://www.joelambert.co.uk/flux/)', but I can't seem to figure it out (I'm rusty - my current job is very "basic" when it comes to programming and I haven't worked properly with javascript/jquery in a couple of years)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which browser are you using? I know it's for sake of example, but binding an variable to `window` like that!

Comment: I won't lie, i just took the code as-is from the demo.  Every example I've seen looks different to it, but I'm just so out of practise I don't want to mess too much with anything unless I have to.

I'm using chrome, firefox and safari (most recent versions), but not ie (yet).

Comment: Ah! So you're just asking if you want too add `transitions: 'bars3d'`?

Comment: I guess so - but where? That's kind of why i feel stupid - I added it, but clearly in the wrong place.

Comment: This is untested although, `pagination : true, transitions: ['bars3d']` should be it

Comment: oh and no worries, it isn't a stupid question at all, sorry if I sounded like that way, apologies.

Comment: yep - that did the trick. Thank you so much - I was using () brackets.  I'm embarrassed to admit that I spent almost 90 minutes futzing with it to get it to work.  

Thank you, again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you make the instance of a new flux.slider, just add to the option object parameter the key **transitions** with, as value, an array with a single element.

The element is a string containing 'bars3d'.

I edited the relevant part of your code

For complete reference see https://github.com/joelambert/Flux-Slider

```
window.f = new flux.slider('#slider', { 
  pagination : true,
  transitions: ['bars3d']
});
```

Comment: thank you - I was close...i tried without the square brackets, then with round brackets.  So happy it's working and now I can get on with the rest of the project.  You guys are great :)